# prevent to send info to datatabse after validate jQuery datatable rows

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have developep a MVC C# App, and there is this view which has a form with three inputs(name, DUI, ISSS) and a jQuery Datatable with three columns(name, DUI, ISSS) that is populated from a database in order to shows its info to the user, the logic is this: the user enters info about a customer(name, DUI, ISSS) into the inputs fields then press the Add button and the app stores the info into the database and after that populates the datatable in the View, but there are two validations:
two customers can have the same DUI neither ISSS value, so what I do is the below script validations:

```
 $("#sentInfo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var table = $('#myTable');

        table.find('tbody tr').each(function (index, tr) {
            if ($(tr).find("td:eq(1)").html() === $("#idDUI").val()) {
                alert('DUI number already exists');
                exit;
            }

            else if ($(tr).find("td:eq(2)").html() === $("#idISSS").val()) {
                alert('the ISSS number already exists');
                exit;
            }
            else {
                $("#FormEmp").submit();
            }
        });
});
```

the problem is that it shows the alert messages but also (sometimes)sends the info to the MVC controller and what I want is that the user can stores the info into the database if the DUI or ISSS already are displaying into the datatable, could you help me?

I have noticed that everytime the button submits the info is when the ISSS validations runs first, and it is supposed that the DUI validation must run first.

the jquery datatable code goes below:

```
 function cargarTabla() { 
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            paging: true,
            responsive: true,
            ordering: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            processing: true,
            info: false,
            deferRender: true,
            orderMulti: false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento,
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "nombres", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                    { "data": "dui", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                    { "data": "numero_isss", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                    { "defaultContent": " <a href='#' id='select'>Modificar</a>  ", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false }
            ],
```

and the HTML table is:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Nombres</th>
             <th>Apellidos</th>
             <th>DUI</th>
             <th>ISSS</th>
             <th>Cargo</th>
             <th>Sexo</th>
             <th>Nivel</th>
             <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: What does your html and datatable instantiation look like?

Comment: I just edited the questions with the code

Comment: if you want to break `each` loop then replace `exit` with `return false`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are submitting form in `each` loop so if it doesn't find matching `DUI` and `ISSS` then it is going to submit form. For next iteration it validates values for next `tr` so it finds matching data then it will display `alert` but your form already submitted.